# C++ : How to count the number of threads used to call a function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to know how many different threads used an object function during its lifetime.

My naive approach was to create a base class to register the id of calling threads :

```
class threaded_object
{
public:
    virtual ~threaded_object() {}

protected:
    void register_call()
    {
                    // error ! if the ID is reused, the new thread wont be accounted for.
        callers_ids.insert(std::this_thread::get_id());
    }

    size_t get_threads_cout() const
    {
        return callers_ids.size();
    }

private:
    std::set<std::thread::id> callers_ids;
};
```

And to inherits it in my client classes, here I will count how many threads used foo()

```
class MyObject : public threaded_object
{
 void foo()
 {
    register_call();
    // ...
 }
};
```

But it doesn't work in the general case, the standards says in section § 30.3.1.1

> The library may reuse the value of a thread::id of a terminated thread
>   that can no longer be joined

**Question:**

Is there a portable and safe way to do this ?

Comment: If 1) the thread id that created the object got reused and 2) only the original creator is allowed to use the object, how do you envision the object being used after the original creator terminated without bothering to destroy the object?

Comment: Seeing as if this ever happens, it is a result of a bug, you should be happy with a detection scheme that works only sometimes. If you have a bug, your code could well have undefined behaviour too, and there isn't really much you can do at that point. If you can catch some bugs, it is better than nothing.

Comment: I see your point. I reformulate with a more general question : my issue is how to uniquely identify threads during the lifetime of the entire program. An example is to count how many different threads called a given function of an object. If I'm not clear Ill just close the question.

Comment: @quantdev: which threads are you interested in ? Specifically, a library is allowed to cache threads, so joining a `std::thread` does not necessarily mean the backing OS-thread was terminated: the thread may be cached, cleaned and reused later. Would you consider this the same thread or a different thread ?

Comment: @Matthieu : yes I would consider it different (actually, answer to both cases are interesting, I believe)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use thread-local storage to count how many threads called your function:

```
namespace {
    thread_local bool used = false;
}


void register_call()
{
    if( !used ) {
        used = true;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Of course this code is to show the idea, in real code it can be a pointer to container, that holds addresses of functions which are in interest etc.

Comment: the `++count` must be atomic operation if you want to count total number of threads

Comment: @Anton probably yes, but again code there is not to be used as it is, but to show the idea. In real code one bool variable would not be enough anyway as author wants to use it for multiple functions, not only one